# Is it possible to use OpenCV module in PyScript?

Tags: python, opencv, pyscript

I want to use opencv module but I can't import OpenCV. So how can I solve this problem?
By the way, Pyodide supports OpenCV.

[Example Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahwex.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do not use links to provide question details. Create self-contained questions. Links change, break, etc rendering your question useless in the future.

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV is not supported yet.

At this time, OpenCV requires `pypi-json`. Loading that package via Pyscript micropip throws a CORS error. Once that is fixed, I am not sure which other problems will surface.

This means some OpenCV dependencies must be corrected first.

**[UPDATE]**

This link [infers](https://github.com/pyodide/pyodide/discussions/2424) that the Pyodide **dev** branch now supports openCV. I have not verified that information.

Comment: Hi Mr. John, thanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you loaded it as a module in your HTML?

```html
  <py-env>
  - bokeh
  - numpy
    ....
  - OpenCV
  </py-env>
```

Comment: I added as <py-env> - cv2 <py-env>.

Comment: Are you also importing as usual in your file? Try opencv-python. Do you get an error when you try to use the module?

Comment: the import is called `cv2` but the PyPI package is called `opencv-python`

Comment: As I understand, I editted the question part. You can find example code in "Example Code".

Comment: @Yılmaz ALACA I'm confused then. Did it work yet? If that is the solution that works, make it clear in the edited answer.  Plus, don't put in code as an image. You'll want to put it in as a text code block.  I like the second and third way listed [here](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/5-ways-to-embed-code-in-stack-overflow-8d9f38edf02c). Those options will serve you well posting code at StackOverflow here and in the future.

Comment: @Wayne it didn't work. Thanks for your advice. When I learned, I will put like your posting code.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz sir, please make an example about this topic. I really need it.